Mixing between the tonic and dominant in melodic dictation
I’m working on functional ear training and practicing melodic dictation, and I noticed a recurring error I make: I sometimes mistake the dominant for the tonic.
When I’m not sure about the tonic I either deduce the correct tonic logically, or write two options, bet on one of them and discover it’s the wrong one when I check myself.
For instance, consider a melody that goes: Do Re Me Re Do Ti La Sol
To my ears, this sounds like: Fa Sol La Sol Fa Mi Re Do
The only reason I would choose the first (correct, according to the exercise) answer is that I know logically that exercises tend to start and end on Do Mi and Sol.
Why does that happen? Is the melody ambiguous? Is there something specific I should train on to hear the correct tonic?

In your example wouldn’t you be confusing the subdominant with the tonic, not the dominant? Mi-Fa and Ti-Do being confused?

@ToddWilcox No, I hear the final Sol as a Do and work everything backwards from there

Oh I get it now.

Are you transcribing records by yourself, or is it part of a school training? I.e. is there a teacher who gives the dictation? Do they provide extra clues?

@user1079505 this question comes from the accompanying materials for “Manual for Ear Training and Sight Singing”, which I am working on on my own.

If you keep switching the tonic to the dominant again and again you can write some interesting music.

@Wastrel I’ll try that!

A melody is necessarily ambiguous, being made up of single notes only, and chords being at most implied. This is common to composition, where choice of harmony can give very different meaning to a melody.
Now, in this exercise you seem to have a limitation to diatonic melodies, that is, melodies only using natural scale degrees. If we were assume a major scale there is only one such scale featuring all 7 notes. All other scales must differ at least by one note. If by chance the melody does not incorporate this distinctive notes it will be ambiguous. The smallest change to get from one scale to a different one is the one that differs by a fifth up (by raising the 4th scale degree) or down (by lowering the 7th scale degree). In your example one scale degree is not given, which happens to be the 4th scale degree starting with do or the 7th one ending on do.
So in this sense your example is really ambiguous. If it is not (all relevant scale degrees are features) and you still have issues discerning the scale look out for these tones. If the 4th scale degree (Fa) happens to be sharp you are sitting on the sub-dominant, if the 7th (Ti) happens to be flat you are on the dominant.
In ambiguous or more generally in chromatic cases it is harder the discern the most likely tonic. General hints are:

The ending note
The starting note
Cadences
Leading tone behaviour


This makes perfect sense, thank you!

A melody is not “necessarily ambiguous” — plenty of melodies are essentially unambiguous even from a couple of bars (e.g. Ein Mädchen oder Weibchen, or the main Star Wars theme) — and conversely, harmonised work can remain ambiguous, e.g. many Chopin openings.  The crux of this question is that OP’s melody is much more ambiguous than most, for reasons elaborated in other answers.

@PLL None of your examples necessitate a specific harmonization. They imply a harmony, which is something I mentioned in the reply. An the reasons elaborated in other answers I do give too, just with more context.

The melody is 100% ambiguous, as you have either ti but not fa, or fa but not ti.  With no other context, either example is equally correct!
Let's pretend the notes yu have heard are CDEDCBAG.  We don't know whether the remaining note will be F or F#.  If the former, CDE is Do Re MI.  If the latter, CDE is indeed Fa Sol La.
It is for this reason that introduction to many popular songs includes the V7 chord or the IV and V chords in succession; this removes all doubt as to where the tonic lies!

Good to know I am not completely off base:)

This melody starts with the tonic  and "modulates" to the dominant in the secound bar. That's why you here first I V I V and then: IV I V I.
It's not quite a modulation but a short extension to the dominant by a V/V that we call a secondary dominant, so it is quite natural that you identify do ti la so like fa mi re do.
I guess you come right now with this question as you have this song in mind:




Thanks! Actually it’s an exercise from an ear training book :)

Even exercise nooks may be based on x-mas Songs  like e.g. Silent Night. Another ex. is We Hall Overcome.


this question comes from the accompanying materials for “Manual for Ear Training and Sight Singing”, which I am working on on my own.

I don't know this book, but normally, a person without perfect pitch needs an additional clue to align the melody. For example, in a dictation exercise, commonly the first note is named. Or a named chord is played at the beginning, etc.
Double check if such clues are provided in the book. If not, maybe you did the exercise the best it was possible for you.

Is the melody ambiguous?

In principle, all melodies are "ambiguous". Any chords could be played with any melody. Some melodies may suggest some harmony more than others, but there is no fail proof way to determine it, at least not without additional clues or restrictions.
Some of the ways for a melody to suggest harmony are:

using chord tones on strong parts of the measure, and placing passing tones, in particular the "avoid notes", on weak parts of the measure
resolving tensions following common patterns
outlining the chords with arpeggios
using longer note values for the chord tones.


'Any chords could be played with any melody'. I guess they could, although some would sound pretty awful!
